# SSL Error during Chef-Solo Tomcat7 Cookbook Installation

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, openssl, chef-infra

An error occurred during the installation of [Tomcat 7 Cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat).
While executing in Chef-Solo, this error appeared. The openssl is correctly installed.

```
  * execute[Create Tomcat SSL certificate] action run
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[Create Tomcat SSL certificate]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '127'
---- Begin output of /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore "/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks" -storepass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -keypass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -dname "cn=localhost" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: sh: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool: not found
---- End output of /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore "/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks" -storepass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -keypass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -dname "cn=localhost" ----
Ran /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore "/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks" -storepass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -keypass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -dname "cn=localhost" returned 127


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /root/.chef/chef-repo/cookbooks/tomcat/recipes/default.rb

181:   execute "Create Tomcat SSL certificate" do
182:     group node['tomcat']['group']
183:     command "#{node['tomcat']['keytool']} -genkeypair -keystore \"#{node['tomcat']['config_dir']}/#{node['tomcat']['keystore_file']}\" -storepass \"#{node['tomcat']['keystore_password']}\" -keypass \"#{node['tomcat']['keystore_password']}\" -dname \"#{node['tomcat']['certificate_dn']}\""
184:     umask 0007
185:     creates "#{node['tomcat']['config_dir']}/#{node['tomcat']['keystore_file']}"
186:     action :run
187:     notifies :restart, "service[tomcat]"
188:   end
189: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /root/.chef/chef-repo/cookbooks/tomcat/recipes/default.rb:181:in `from_file'

execute("Create Tomcat SSL certificate") do
  action [:run]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  command "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore \"/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks\" -storepass \"AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi\" -keypass \"AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi\" -dname \"cn=localhost\""
  backup 5
  creates "/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks"
  group "tomcat7"
  returns 0
  umask 7
  cookbook_name :tomcat
  recipe_name "default"
end



  * service[tomcat] action restart
    - restart service service[tomcat]

[2014-02-04T10:42:24-02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-02-04T10:42:24-02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 5 resources updated
[2014-02-04T10:42:24-02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-02-04T10:42:24-02:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[Create Tomcat SSL certificate] (tomcat::default line 181) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '127'
---- Begin output of /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore "/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks" -storepass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -keypass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -dname "cn=localhost" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: sh: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool: not found
---- End output of /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore "/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks" -storepass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -keypass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -dname "cn=localhost" ----
Ran /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore "/etc/tomcat7/keystore.jks" -storepass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -keypass "AWpbettrAMoVK4orJOdi" -dname "cn=localhost" returned 127
```

If somebody have a idea for resolve this, pls, answer :)

Comment: Is java installed on the system?

Comment: Of course. TomCat depends java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known tomcat cookbook issue: [COOK-4097](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-4097)

You can work-around this problem by assigning the correct path to the keytool executable:

```
override["tomcat"]["keytool"] = "/usr/bin/keytool"
```

I have a [working example](https://github.com/myspotontheweb/chef-demo), check the attributes section of the cookbook:

- https://github.com/myspotontheweb/chef-demo/blob/master/attributes/default.rb