# Tomcat Cookbook Failure due to SSL Error

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra, vagrant, cookbook

Using vagrant-berkshelf, I'm trying to provision Tomcat on my Vagrant CentOS box.

Here's the error:

```
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ sudo cat /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[Create Tomcat SSL certificate]
  (tomcat::default line 128) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed:
     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore 
     "/etc/tomcat6/keystore.jks" -storepass "mGSXXns5lCmugUp3VjBK" 
     -keypass "mGSXXns5lCmugUp3VjBK" -dname "cn=localhost" ----
STDOUT: Usage:  keytool [COMMAND] [-- COMMAND]...
Manage private keys and public certificates.
```

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553108/ssl-error-during-chef-solo-tomcat7-cookbook-installation), so I overrode the `tomcat.keytool` attribute (see below), yet still got the same error.

```
    "tomcat" => {
      "keytool" => "/usr/bin/keytool"
    }
```

**EDIT**

It looks like the above linked's question pointed to a Debian/Ubuntu bug (https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-4097?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel) that's been fixed.

When I removed the `tomcat.keytool` information, and then `vagrant destroy`ed and re-ran `vagrant up --provision`, I got the same above error. Then, I ran `vagrant provision` without any errors, and tomcat was running. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It seems like `keytool` is called with wrong parameters. Try to run the command (`/usr/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore 
     "/etc/tomcat6/keystore.jks" -storepass "mGSXXns5lCmugUp3VjBK" 
     -keypass "mGSXXns5lCmugUp3VjBK" -dname "cn=localhost"`) by hand and figure out, what the parameters is wrong.

Comment: And the linked bug doesn't affect you. The path to `keytool` is correct, "only" the passed parameters are wrong.